# Menu not showing on some content types

Tags: panels

I have an inherited website that uses panels, and the menu is not coming out on certain pages . how can I find out and fix it so that the menu comes out on all of the pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple places to start looking:

1. **Block configuration**

   Is the menu placed as a block with specific logic that prevents it from appearing on certain pages. Go to 'Structure >> Blocks' and see if there is a block placed for your menu. Then under 'Visibility Settings'.
2. **[Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context)**

   Is the menu placed via Context? 'Structure >> Context', look for something that has to do with the menu.
3. **Page Manager**

   Is the menu part of the page template or is it specifically placed in the content section of each page?  Check out a page that shows the menu and a page that doesn't in the page manager, go to 'content' of the applicable variant and see if you can spot any differences.

With out some more information it is hard to determine what method is being used to place the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I found the answer, it was in a custom module that was looking for a context id that it didnt find.  thanks